# Can I use CSS "unicode-range" to specify a font across an entire (third party) page?

Tags: css, unicode, font-face, stylish, southeast-asian-languages

I've never become fluent with CSS but I don't think I had this situation before.

I'm thinking of using **[stylish](http://userstyles.org)** to add CSS to a third-party site over which I have no direct control. So the HTML and CSS is not really set up for the kind of customizations I want to do.

The site I wish to tweak doesn't allow good control over fonts but some of its pages (user created) make a lot of use of some exotic Unicode ranges (eg. Khmer) that my OS/browser combination choose a terrible font for:

[image: two muppets]

Can I make a CSS rule that will apply to all text in a page that falls within a certain Unicode range to set it to a known good font, without delving into the structure of the page HTML/DOM?

(Or is `unicode-range` only for doing something different with webfonts?

Comment: The question would be much more understandable if you showed an example of what you are trying to do and shared your experiences with it on different browsers.

Comment: Yes I haven't got so far yet, and the strange language might throw people off but let me give it a shot ...

Comment: Did you ever find a good answer for this? I'm in the same boat now. The non-latin characters are too small. The range is there, but can't set a font size based on it.

Comment: @VirtualLife: I can't actually remember. My comments on the answers make it sound like I didn't find a real solution but might've found a partial solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes in most browsers

[**MDN - Unicode Range**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-range)

> The unicode-range CSS descriptor sets the specific range of characters
>   to be downloaded from a font defined by @font-face and made available
>   for use on the current page.

Example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ampersand';
  src: local('Times New Roman');
  unicode-range: U+26;
}
```

Support: [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-unicode-range)

Also see this [**Article**](http://24ways.org/2011/creating-custom-font-stacks-with-unicode-range/)

Comment: Without checking it **should** override too but you would have to test

Comment: Not having any luck yet, but what do each of the two fonts `Ampersand` and `Times New Roman` refer to? Is one the font that would render and the other that I'm telling it to render instead for that range?

Comment: Check out the Article..you have to 'name' your range (in this case we make up a new `font-family` of `Ampersand`) for usage purposes and the `Times New Roman` is the substitute font you want to use for that range.

Comment: I'm combining parts of your answer and Jon Holland's and adding specific classes to the stylish CSS as I find parts that are not corrected by the global styling. Seems to be the closest I can get.

Answer (score 1):

unicode-range(s) can be used to specify which specific set (or range) of characters you want to be downloaded from a font in an attempt to save bandwidth.  See here:  [Mozilla unicode-range info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-range)

Without seeing the actual CSS you could attempt to just force a different font to be used completely by doing something such as declaring

```
body{font-family: arial,sans-serif;}
```

or adding !important (which I would avoid under any normal circumstance) if the other fonts refuse to give way e.g.

```
body{font-family: arial,sans-serif !important;}
```

If you can bypass using the original font faces then the unicode-ranges will cease to be important.  Watch out for things like icon-fonts though as removing those may make certain symbols/graphics disappear.

Hope that helps.

Sorry I rather misunderstood your question - thought you wanted rid of the existing unicode fonts altogether.

Comment: I'm combining parts of your answer and Paulie_D's and adding specific classes to the stylish CSS as I find parts that are not corrected by the global styling. Seems to be the closest I can get.

Comment: I know this is rather far on but I was recently tasked with solving a rogue character problem on a copy of a site where they were showing in one location and not at another.  The problems on the wonky site were caused by the httpd settings on the server set to force a specific charset on all output.  Looks for http.conf and the AddDefaultCharset setting.  Just one more thing to watch out for.